# Sharepoint Library Item view -Item Count and Who viewed the Item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

How to check when a library item is viewed in a SharePoint library? We cant use Event Receivers as it contains the events Item Added,Item Updated and Deleted Events. In the case of viewing a document how can we track who viewed the page/How many times.I am using SharePoint 2010 development environment.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can set up item level auditing. Instructions can be found [here](http://sharepointthomas.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-enable-audit-functionality-in.html). And if you want to retrieve audit data in code you can use [SPAudit.GetEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457256%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I found if the site has more than 1000 users it has limitations. So i thought of developing some custom action for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the usage report through WSS_Logging database, check this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh769360%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more information or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70865/SharePoint-2010-Logging-Database

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ram for your answer. This is the first time I heard about this. I will check the Database and confirm wether i can get the required columns. Thanks again.

Comment: @ Ram Checked the logging database but there is no information on List Views. Feels like when a document gets checked out it adds a entry not when it is viewed.